# Intermittently getting old data from mysql innodb queries

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, locking, innodb

We have various tables to represent various types of data. Each table has a corresponding revisions table to track history of this data. Each revision (entry in a revisions table) has a unique number. This number is stored in a change metadata table. Each of these tables references a parent_id. Before we make any changes to the tables we lock the parent row with SELECT … FOR UPDATE.

After making an update/insert we also increment the change number and write that number to the change metadata table. To do so we do a SELECT MAX on the change metadata number and then increment it.

The issue we’re seeing is that somehow a transaction is getting an old change number from the select max statement. To illustrate:

Transaction 1:

START TRANSACTION

lock with FOR UPDATE

do stuff...

Get Latest Change Number (9)

Insert Revision with Number 10

COMMIT

Transaction 2:

START TRANSACTION

lock with FOR UPDATE

do stuff...

Get Latest Change Number (7)

Insert Revision with Number 8

COMMIT

This causes the revision insert for transaction 2 to fail as the change number is a unique key. I’m leaning towards it being an issue of repeatable reads but I’m not sure how the old data can persist across transactions in such a way. For each transactions there's a START TRANSACTION statement and then immediately the parent id is locked with FOR UPDATE. We have a high traffic site with multiple concurrent transactions. It's possible there are many waiting on the lock at any one time. I'd be happy to clarify any point and would appreciate any insight anyone could offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SELECT MAX on the change metadata number

That needs `FOR UPDATE`, too.

Another approach:

Have a "sequence number generator" table.

```
CREATE TABLE Sequence (
    pk TINYINT NOT NULL,
    seq INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(pk),   -- For ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    INDEX(seq)         -- Sufficient for AUTO_INCREMENT
);
```

The only action (once initialized) should be

```
INSERT INTO Sequence (pk, seq) VALUE (1, 0)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE seq := LAST_INSERT_ID(seq+1);
```

That will update the one row atomically.  Then (in the same connection), do this to get the new `seq`:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

That statement is tied to the connection, so there is no chance of someone else getting your number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can understand locking the select of the actual change number. I sort of inherited this code so I'm not 100% why certain things were done. Shouldn't those initial FOR UPDATE statements ensure there's only one transaction getting a new change number at any one point?

Comment: Yes, it seems like `FOR UPDATE` on both `SELECTs` should have sufficed.  What transaction mode were you using.

Comment: Are you referring to isolation mode? The default, repeatable read

Comment: Adding a FOR UPDATE effectively fixed my issue, although I still don't know WHY